# how to remove text link without removing entire class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a link in the h3 , i used the following but it's removing the entire h3 , and i only want the link that contains the text "Skin" removed. The actual URL is always changing from server to server , the only part of the URL string that remains in place is "O=128&F

```
$("h3:contains('Skin')").remove();


h3>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="THE URL ALWAYS CHANGES EXCEPT FOR THIS PART 'O=128&F' ">
        Skin
    </a>
</h3>
```

Comment: If you only want to remove the link, then you have to select the link , not the `h3` heading.

Comment: also how many anchors do you want to put inside that h3 ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("h3 a:contains('Skin')").remove();
```

You need to target the links within the h3. The link will contain the text.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the h3:contains to a:contains?

Comment: wow , i'm really tired , thanks for the catch dont know what i was doing

Comment: Happens to me all the time.  :)